# How to redirect GUI events into system.in or System.out into GUI components?

Tags: java, user-interface, cmd

I've created a simple command line interface server application that reads `System.in` in order to operate. It accepts simple commands:

`START` to start the ServerSocket and listening for client connections.

`STOP`, to broadcast to all clients that the server is closing, and close the ServerSocket.

`ONLINEUSERS`. to see which user is online.

It worked quite well.
Then, It need its GUI interface.

Say that I have `Server` class with `main()` to start the server process (but still idle, because the `START` command is not entered yet) and a plain `ServerGUI` with start button (`JButton`) and log text area(`JTextArea`).

As to minimize coupling, is it possible to design a program that: first, start the server with its `Server.main()`; second, start the ServerGUI; then, when the start button in the ServerGUI is clicked, it automatically send `START` command to the process and started the server?

Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question is trying to find a way to pipe data into the System object such that monitors of System.in will get it.  There may be a way to do that, but it is not how I would go about it.

Instead I would register an event handler with your STart button and have that call a method on the server class.

Something like the following would work.

```
startButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
startButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
         Server.startSocketAndListen();
     }
});
```